# Calculation within a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to include a 4th "Program" within my case statement that would be a combination of ALL programs added together since there is no Table ID that identifies for ALL (i.e. pp.id=2 + p.id=3 + p.id=4 = All). Is a CASE statement able to achieve this? COALESCE? A nested SELECT?

```
   DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, getdate())

Select Count(Distinct fm.MEMBER_ID) As 'Count',
      Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' + Cast(DatePart(MONTH,
      dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE) As 'Month',
      Case When p.ID = 2 Then 'Program1' When p.ID = 3 Then 'Program2'
        When p.ID = 4 Then 'Program3' End As 'Program'
    From FACT_MEMBER_MONTH_START fm
      Join DIM_COVERAGE c On fm.MEMBER_ID = c.MEMBER_ID
      Join DIM_PROGRAM p On c.PROGRAM_ID = p.ID
      Join DIM_DATE dd On fm.MONTH_ID = dd.MONTH_ID
      Join DIM_MEMBER dm On fm.MEMBER_ID = dm.ID
      Join DIM_INDIVIDUAL DI On fm.MEMBER_ID = DI.ID
      Join DIM_LIVING_SITUATION dls On fm.LIVING_SITUATION_ID = dls.ID
    Where dd.DATE Between c.EFFECTIVE_DATE And c.EXPIRATION_DATE And (dls.ID = 5
        Or dls.ID = 6) and (dd.DATE between DATEADD(MM, -18, @date) and @date)
    Group By Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' +
      Cast(DatePart(MONTH, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE),
      Case When p.ID = 2 Then 'FC' When p.ID = 3 Then 'PACE'
        When p.ID = 4 Then 'Part' End
 ORDER BY Month desc
```

Results:

[image: Sample Results]

End goal would be a "4th Program" that is just a summation of the 3. This is to be used in Logi Analytics to develop multiple charts off one query that can be filtered using these separate programs.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would be helpful.  Are you getting duplicates with Program1, 2 and 3 now that you want to rollup to Program4?

Comment: What flavor and version of SQL?

Comment: How can a single column in a single row, `p.id`, have three different values at once?

Comment: Also, because you are doing a lot of text manipulation on a date value (`Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' + Cast(DatePart(MONTH,
      dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE)'), you would see a very big performance improvement by using a Date Dimension.

Comment: `P.ID` cannot have the values `2`, `4`, and `6` at the same time. Is this quantum computing? ;)

Comment: @Shawn I added a results image and explanation what I am aiming at. Date Dimension is not something I've messed with. Sorry I am still pretty new to SQL.

Comment: @Shawn: SSMS is a SQL Server thing IIRC.

Comment: @stickybit The CASE statement is counting distinct members who belong to each p.id and assigning them to the Program column.

Comment: @BobJarvis I know, but the DBMS should still be included in the question. And since there are differences between versions, that info is very helpful also.

Comment: @Pat: Nope it doesn't count anything. It just maps the value of `p.id` (single column of a single row) to some string in the form of "Program <n>". You should definitely follow the advise to post sample data and expected results (not wrong results) to make this clearer. Please post them as formatted text or the sample data ideally as `INSERT INTO` statements (ideally along with the `CREATE TABLE` statements) not as screenshots (they make it hard to setup a test environment if someone wants to test their solution).

Comment: Sample data for each of your related tables would be very helpful. There are a lot of tables here that could be adding unintentional rows to your counts.

Comment: @stickybit Noted. Sorry, first time submitting.

Comment: Also, you are doing a lot of filtering in the `WHERE` clause. It's probably better to do them in their actual JOIN. It probably won't change your ultimate results in `INNER JOIN`s like above, but it could easily change your results if you had `OUTER JOIN`s. Just a good habit to get in to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about a UNION ALL,  putting together your Program1, Program2, Program3  and adding new rows for Program4

```
   DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, getdate())

Select Count(Distinct fm.MEMBER_ID) As 'Count',
      Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' + Cast(DatePart(MONTH,
      dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE) As 'Month',
      Case When p.ID = 2 Then 'Program1' When p.ID = 3 Then 'Program2'
        When p.ID = 4 Then 'Program3' End As 'Program'
    From FACT_MEMBER_MONTH_START fm
      Join DIM_COVERAGE c On fm.MEMBER_ID = c.MEMBER_ID
      Join DIM_PROGRAM p On c.PROGRAM_ID = p.ID
      Join DIM_DATE dd On fm.MONTH_ID = dd.MONTH_ID
      Join DIM_MEMBER dm On fm.MEMBER_ID = dm.ID
      Join DIM_INDIVIDUAL DI On fm.MEMBER_ID = DI.ID
      Join DIM_LIVING_SITUATION dls On fm.LIVING_SITUATION_ID = dls.ID
    Where dd.DATE Between c.EFFECTIVE_DATE And c.EXPIRATION_DATE And (dls.ID = 5
        Or dls.ID = 6) and (dd.DATE between DATEADD(MM, -18, @date) and @date)
    Group By Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' +
      Cast(DatePart(MONTH, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE),
      Case When p.ID = 2 Then 'FC' When p.ID = 3 Then 'PACE'
        When p.ID = 4 Then 'Part' End

UNION ALL

Select Count(Distinct fm.MEMBER_ID) As 'Count',
      Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' + Cast(DatePart(MONTH,
      dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE) As 'Month',

      'Program4' as 'Program'  -- they are all Program4

    From FACT_MEMBER_MONTH_START fm
      Join DIM_COVERAGE c On fm.MEMBER_ID = c.MEMBER_ID
      Join DIM_PROGRAM p On c.PROGRAM_ID = p.ID
      Join DIM_DATE dd On fm.MONTH_ID = dd.MONTH_ID
      Join DIM_MEMBER dm On fm.MEMBER_ID = dm.ID
      Join DIM_INDIVIDUAL DI On fm.MEMBER_ID = DI.ID
      Join DIM_LIVING_SITUATION dls On fm.LIVING_SITUATION_ID = dls.ID
    Where dd.DATE Between c.EFFECTIVE_DATE And c.EXPIRATION_DATE And (dls.ID = 5
        Or dls.ID = 6) and (dd.DATE between DATEADD(MM, -18, @date) and @date)
    Group By Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' +
      Cast(DatePart(MONTH, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/01' As DATE)

 ORDER BY Month desc, Program
```

Comment: This is producing exactly what I needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what you want is something like:

```
Select Count(Distinct fm.MEMBER_ID) As 'Count',
       Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' +
            Cast(DatePart(MONTH, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) +
            '/01' As DATE) As 'Month',
       Case
         When p.ID = 2 Then 'Program1'
         When p.ID = 3 Then 'Program2'
         When p.ID = 4 Then 'Program3'
       End As 'Program'
  From FACT_MEMBER_MONTH_START fm
  Join DIM_COVERAGE c On fm.MEMBER_ID = c.MEMBER_ID
  Join DIM_PROGRAM p On c.PROGRAM_ID = p.ID
  Join DIM_DATE dd On fm.MONTH_ID = dd.MONTH_ID
  Join DIM_MEMBER dm On fm.MEMBER_ID = dm.ID
  Join DIM_INDIVIDUAL DI On fm.MEMBER_ID = DI.ID
  Join DIM_LIVING_SITUATION dls On fm.LIVING_SITUATION_ID = dls.ID
  Where dd.DATE Between c.EFFECTIVE_DATE And c.EXPIRATION_DATE And
        (dls.ID = 5 Or
         dls.ID = 6) and
        (dd.DATE between DATEADD(MM, -18, @date) and @date)
  Group By ROLLUP Cast(Cast(DatePart(YEAR, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) + '/' +
                       Cast(DatePart(MONTH, dd.DATE) As VARCHAR) +
                       '/01' As DATE),
                  p.ID
  ORDER BY Month desc
```

Answer (score 0):

This query can be simplified a bit. There are a few things not needed, and there are also a few performance choke-points that could be improved.

```
DECLARE @date datetime = CONVERT(date, getdate()) ;  
/* 
    NOTE: getDate() returns a datetime datatype. No need to CONVERT(). 
    But, I'm guessing this input is coming in as an application input. In 
    that case, it will probably still need the CONVERT().
*/

/* s1 CTE holds the base data for the later UNIONs. */
; WITH s1 AS ( 
    SELECT Count(Distinct fm.MEMBER_ID) AS [Count]
          /* 
            There is a lot of heavy string processing for @date that can be avoided. Also, we 
            may not need the CAST. It will return the datatype of @date 
          */
        , CAST( CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(day,-DAY(@date)+1,@date),111) AS date) AS [Month] 
        , CASE C.PROGRAM_ID
            WHEN 2 THEN 'Program1' 
            When 3 Then 'Program2'
            When 4 Then 'Program3' 
          END AS Program
    FROM FACT_MEMBER_MONTH_START fm
        INNER JOIN DIM_COVERAGE c On fm.MEMBER_ID = c.MEMBER_ID
            AND c.PROGRAM_ID IN ( 2,3,4 ) /* Do we only care about these programs? */
          /* Join DIM_PROGRAM p On c.PROGRAM_ID = p.ID */ /* Is this table needed? */
        INNER JOIN DIM_DATE dd On fm.MONTH_ID = dd.MONTH_ID
            AND dd.DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(month, -18, @date) AND @date
            AND dd.DATE BETWEEN c.EFFECTIVE_DATE AND c.EXPIRATION_DATE
        /* DIM_DATE JOIN should be able to be much simplified. */     
        INNER JOIN DIM_MEMBER dm ON fm.MEMBER_ID = dm.ID
        INNER JOIN DIM_INDIVIDUAL DI ON fm.MEMBER_ID = DI.ID
        INNER JOIN DIM_LIVING_SITUATION dls ON fm.LIVING_SITUATION_ID = dls.ID
            AND dls.ID IN ( 5, 6 )  /* Since we were filtering with these, just use in JOIN. */
    GROUP BY 
        CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(day,-DAY(dd.DATE)+1,dd.DATE),111) /* Simplified */
        , c.PROGRAM_ID
) 
SELECT s1.[Month]
    , s1.[Count]
    , s1.Program
FROM s1    

UNION ALL

SELECT s.[Month]
    , SUM(s.[Count]) AS [Count]
    , 'Program4' AS Program
FROM s1 s    
GROUP BY s.[Month]

ORDER BY [Month],Program
```

I use a Common Table Expression (CTE) (`s1`) to get the totals for the `Program`s per month, then `SELECT` that from the CTE, which should give me a count breakdown of all of the `Month`s and `Program`s. I then `SELECT` again from the CTE and just `SUM()` all of the programs by `Month` and then `UNION ALL` that back into the first query. That should give me a row for Program4 for the `Month`.

I'm not sure how this needs to be sent to your charting system, but this query can also be transformed into a `PIVOT` so that each `Month` has only one row.

***DISCLAIMER:** Without data I can't test this, but it should run a bit faster and still return the same data as before. You may have to adjust your filters.*

Comment: Note: I think using `CONVERT(varchar,DATEADD(day,-DAY(@date)+1,@date),111) AS date)` to build your date will probably be thing biggest single speed improvement of this query. String concatenation with date manipulation/extraction can become _VERY_ slow.